# Проблема со связными списками

Tags: c++

Код компилируется, но выводится только один список, в порядке, в котором он был создан. А функция `reverse`, которая ставит в обратном порядке элементы, почему-то совершенно бесполезна - я ее вызываю, но ничего не происходит. На выходе список остается неизменным.

Может, проблема в том, что я эту функцию пишу, до того, как создается сам список?

```
struct Data
{
    int a;
};

struct List
{
    Data d;
    List * next;
};

// Рекурсия, инверсия списка
List * reverse(List *u)
{
        if (u == 0) return 0;
        if (u->next == 0) return u;

        List * tmp = reverse(u->next);

        u->next->next = u;
        u->next = 0;
        return tmp;
}

// Находим значения списка
bool Find_Item_Single_List(List * u, int DataItem)
{
    List *ptr; 
    ptr = u;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (DataItem == ptr->d.a) return true;
        else ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    List *u = NULL;

    // 1-й узел
    u = new List; // Объявление
    u->d.a = 3;  
    u->next = NULL; // Указатель на следующий элемент
    // Для удобства создаем переменную-указатель, которая хранит адрес последнего элемента
    List *x;

    // 2-й узел
    x = u;
    x->next = new List;
    x = x->next;
    x->d.a = 5;
    x->next = NULL;
    // 
    List *c;

    // 3-й узел
    c = x;
    c->next = new List;
    c = c->next;
    c->d.a = 1;
    c->next = NULL;
    //
    List *b;

    // 4-й узел
    b = c;
    b->next = new List;
    b = b->next;
    b->d.a = 9;
    b->next = NULL;

    // Вывод (просто идем по списку)
    while(u)
    {
        cout << u->d.a << endl; 
        u = u->next;         
    }

    reverse(u);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что после вызова `reverse(u);` программа сразу заканчиваетс. Перевернутый список вы не выводите.

Comment: ... Причем не только "не выводите", но даже и не сохраняете результат переворачивания. Функция `reverse` возвращает указатель на начало перевернутого списка. Этот указатель надо запоминать и начиная с него выводить перевернутый список.

Comment: https://github.com/samrrr/LABS4/blob/master/L2/code.cpp Класс SET2 список. Тот код, что я вижу от с++ имеет только cin cout. А ведь в с++ есть классы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работать это никак не может потому, что вы своих циклом вывода

```
while(u)
{
    cout << u->d.a << endl; 
    u = u->next;         
}
```

"испортили" значение `u`. После этого цикла `u` содержит нулевой указатель. Доступ к началу вашего списка вы потеряли. Вызов

```
reverse(u);
```

получает на вход этот нулевой указатель и, разумеется, ничего не делает вообще. На этом вы закачиваете программу.

Во-первых, не портьте значение `u` вашим циклом вывода. `u` - это указатель на начало вашего списка. Его вам надо беречь, как зеницу ока. Не пользуйтесь переменной `u` для посторонних целей.

Если вы хотите вывести список - заведите для прохода по списку отдельную переменную

```
for (const List *p = u; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    cout << p->d.a << endl;
```

Во-вторых, функция `reverse` переворачивает ваш список и *возвращает вам новый указатель* на его новое начало. Не забывайте сохранять это значение. Вот тут-то как раз разумно его сохранить в `u`

```
u = reverse(u);
```

В-третьих, если вы хотите напечатать перевернутый список - то печатайте его. У вас в коде нет ни малейших попыток напечатать перевернутый список. Неудивительно, что ничего не печатается. Опять

```
for (const List *p = u; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    cout << p->d.a << endl;
```

Разумеется, для печати вашего списка имеет смысл завести отдельную функцию, а не ляпать в текст программы один и тот же цикл снова и снова.

Comment: Простите) можно вопрос не по месту) а какой опыт у вас в программировании, что вы так все прекрасно знаете? когда то бы и мне хотелось бы обладать такими знаниями)

Comment: @DenSimachov конкретно по этому вопросу достаточно пары месяцев усердного обучения, чтобы свободно понимать что происходит. Я имею в виду контейнер List, указатели, циклы, потоки вывода и умение читать чужой код